# Replacing multiple items with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have a text file that contains certain string sequences that I want to modify. For example, in the following string I would like to replace foo and bar each with a unique string (The new string will be based on what originally matches, so I won't know it before hand).

```
Original: foo text text bar text
Replaced: fooNew text text bar_replaced text
```

I am using regex to find the groups that I need to change based on how they are delimited in the actual text. If I just use re.findAll(), I no longer have the location of the words in the string to reconstruct the string after modifying the matched groups.

Is there a way to preserve the location of the words in the string while modifying each match separately?

Comment: Right after posting this I realized I could probably use str.replace() after re.findAll(), but since I have already typed it out I wonder if anyone has a better way.

Comment: is there a reason not to use `re.sub`?

Comment: If the search strings are hardcode strings and there is no context to account for when matching the strings, use chained `replace` methods.

Comment: @asongtoruin What I will substitute depends on what I find during matching. I can't know what to substitute ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

I would recommend this for complicated scenarios. Here's a solution with `re.sub` and a lambda callback:

```
In [1]: re.sub('foo|bar', lambda x: 'fooNew' if x.group() == 'foo' else 'bar_replaced', text)
Out[1]: 'fooNew text text bar_replaced text'
```

---

**Option 2**

Much simpler, if you have hardcoded strings, the replacement is possible with `str.replace`:

```
In [2]: text.replace('foo', 'fooNew').replace('bar', 'bar_replaced')
Out[2]: 'fooNew text text bar_replaced text'
```

Comment: In "Option 1" can any function go after lambda x: for the new replacement?

Comment: @digitaLink Exactly.