# Replacing non-alphanumeric characters in regex match using Python

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, verilog

I have a text file (verilog) that contains certain string sequences (escaped identifiers) that I want to modify. In the example below, I want to find any group starting with '\' and ending with ' ' (any printable character can be in between). After finding a group that matches this criteria, I want to replace all non-alphanumeric characters with alphanumeric ones (I don't really care what alphanumeric they get replaced with).

```
In[1]:  here i$ \$0me text to \m*dify
Out[1]: here i$ aame text to madify
```

I have no problem finding the groups that need replacing using regex. However, if I just use re.findAll(), I no longer have the location of the words in the string to reconstruct the string after modifying the matched groups.

Is there a way to preserve the location of the words in the string while modifying each match separately?

Note: I previously asked a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45509579/python-regex-replacing-multiple-items), but I oversimplified my example. I thought editing my existing question would make the existing comments and answers confusing to future readers.

Comment: Have you experimented with `re.sub` yet? I think it's capable of taking your modified text and reconstructing the string on its own, without any additional effort on your part. And you can pass a callable for the `repl` parameter of `sub`, so you can execute arbitrary code on each match rather than just replacing it with something static.

Comment: I don't see how my answer to your previous question is not useful to you. It uses `re.sub`, and the same is applicable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer to your previous question still applies, with some minor modifications. Only the regex changes.

Since this is more complex, define a function to pass as a callback.

```
In [57]: def foo(m):
    ...:     return ''.join(x if re.match('[a-zA-Z]', x)\
                              else ('' if x == '\\' else 'a') for x in m.group())
```

Now, call `re.sub`:

```
In [58]: re.sub(r'\\.*?(?= |$)', foo, text)
Out[58]: 'here i$ aame text to madify'
```

Comment: I think I understand now. I didn't realize that a function could be passed into re.sub().

Comment: @digitaLink Yes. If a lambda can go, any function can go. Feel free to mark accepted, thanks!